# Missing Expression in Oracle when I try inserting a variable in update statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create an update which will update the table with a variable declared by me, but it is giving me an error which says"Missing expression". I am at a loss as to what could possibly cause this.

Here is my code.

```
DECLARE
 VBILL BILL%ROWTYPE;
 CURSOR BILLAMT IS
  SELECT * FROM BILL;
 VCUST1 NUMBER(3);
 VCUST2 NUMBER(3);
 VCUST3 NUMBER(3);

BEGIN

 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST1 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=100;
 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST2 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=1000;
 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST3 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=10000;
 OPEN BILLAMT;
 LOOP
  FETCH BILLAMT INTO VBILL;
  EXIT WHEN BILLAMT%NOTFOUND;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VBILL.AMOUNT);
  IF VBILL.AMOUNT>100 and VBILL.AMOUNT<=1000 THEN
   VCUST1:=VCUST1+1;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE('UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY=@VCUST1 WHERE RANGE=100');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VBILL.AMOUNT);
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE BILLAMT;
END;
```

I think the problem is with the execute immediate statement. I even tried this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY=:a WHERE RANGE=100' USING VCUST1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for a DML statement. Just do

```
UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY = VCUST1 WHERE RANGE = 100;
```

And I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I imagine you can do this in a single `UPDATE` statement without the loop, which would make it much more efficient.

Comment: I probably can. But the main thing here was syntax. I am new to Pl/SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the parentheses from the second attempt:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY=:a WHERE RANGE=100'
USING VCUST1;
```

But there is no need for dynamic SQL, it would be better to use `UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY=vcust1 WHERE RANGE=100;`.  Also, it is generally a good idea to avoid CURSOR/OPEN/FETCH/EXIT WHEN/CLOSE.  Implicit cursor for-loops are simpler and faster:

```
DECLARE
 VCUST1 NUMBER(3);
 VCUST2 NUMBER(3);
 VCUST3 NUMBER(3);
BEGIN
 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST1 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=100;
 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST2 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=1000;
 SELECT FREQUENCY INTO VCUST3 FROM RANGEOFBILLS WHERE RANGE=10000;
 FOR VBILL IN (SELECT * FROM BILL) LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VBILL.AMOUNT);
  IF VBILL.AMOUNT>100 and VBILL.AMOUNT<=1000 THEN
   VCUST1:=VCUST1+1;
   UPDATE RANGEOFBILLS SET FREQUENCY=vcust1 WHERE RANGE=100;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VBILL.AMOUNT);
  END IF;
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```